# How to convert the result of jQuery .find() function to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What does jQuery `.find()` method return? a **object** OR a **array list** of objects?

If it returns an object which contain all the matched elements. How to convert this object to an array?

If it returns a array of elements, why `$(xml).find("DATE").sort(mySortFunc);` does not work, it seems the jQuery `.find()` returns an object which can not apply Javascript `sort()` method which is supposed to be applied on array.

Generally, I need to sort the objects find by `$(xml).find("DATE")` , but when I use sort function, it raised an error that the object can not be resolved.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/ ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The majority of jQuery methods returns a jQuery object, which can be accessed like it is an array (e.g. it has a `.length` attribute, elements can be accessed using the square bracket notation (`[0]`), and it supports *some* array methods ([`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice))).

jQuery has a method called [`toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray) which can be used to convert the jQuery object to a real array.

You can also use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) with no arguments to achieve the same effect (and save you a few key presses).

In future, you can checkout the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), and the return type for all jQuery methods is listed in the relevant documentation (e.g. for [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find), the return type is "jQuery")

Comment: Which array methods are supported, which ones not?

Answer (score 7):

If you call [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) on a jQuery object without a parameter, it will return a regular array of DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery already acts like an array, and thus you can apply array like functionality to it.

Try to change

```
$(xml).find("DATE").sort(mySortFunc);
```

with

```
Array.prototype.sort.apply($(xml).find("DATE"), mySortFunc);
```

and you should get what you need